# How to run controller action as ajax in yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I have created a grid called 'Status' in yii2-advanced application. 
I have added a custom button in `backend/views/status/index.php` that is working and calling respective controller action.

My customization is as follows :

```
[ 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 
    'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {status/custom}', 
    'buttons' => [ 
        'status/custom' => function ($url) 
        { 
            return Html::a( 'Custom', $url, 
                    [ 
                        'title' => 'Custom', 
                        'data-pjax' => '0', 
                    ]
                    ); 

        }, 
    ],
],
```

Now I want that the controller action will be call using ajax without page redirect or load.

How to call `actionCustom()` using ajax on click `Custom` button?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve it by using modal.

```
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

use johnitvn\ajaxcrud\CrudAsset;



Html::a('Custom', ['custom'], ['role'=>'modal-remote', 'title'=>'Custom']);
```

In the bottom of the page..

```
<?php Modal::begin([
    "id"=>"ajaxCrudModal",
    "footer"=>"",// always need it for jquery plugin
])?>
<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

In Controller

```
use \yii\web\Response;
```

In the action of controller

```
$request = Yii::$app->request;

 if($request->isAjax){
            /*
            *   Process for ajax request
            */
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            if($request->isGet){
                return [
                    'title'=> "Title",
                    'content'=>$this->renderAjax('
                        'model' => $yourModel
                    ]),
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                                Html::button('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>"submit"])

                ];  
            }else if($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()){


                return [
                    'forceReload'=>'#crud-datatable-pjax',
                    'title'=> "Title",
                    'content'=>'<span class="text-success">Textspan>',
                    'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                            Html::a('Create new',['create', 'id'=>$id],['class'=>'btn btn-primary','role'=>'modal-remote'])

                ];         
            }else{           
             ...        
        }else{
           ...
        }
```